# Yii List view popover

Tags: yii

I am trying to popover a dialog box by clicking a link (Click here) in List view. The popover works fine but when i click any of the Click here link, it shows the title of first data in a list. I want to show corresponding title when clicks the link for each data item.
Index.php

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
)); ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#closebtn").click(function () {
            $("#dlg").hide('800', "swing", function () { $("#bkg").fadeOut("500"); });
          });
          $(".opn").click(function () {
            if (document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
              document.getElementById('bkg').style.visibility = '';
              $("#bkg").hide();
            }
            if (document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility == 'hidden') {
              document.getElementById('dlg').style.visibility = '';
              $("#dlg").hide();
            }
            $("#bkg").fadeIn(500, "linear", function () { $("#dlg").show(800, "swing"); });
          });    

        });
      </script>
```

_view.php

```
<div class="post">
<?php echo $data->title;
echo $data->author;
?> 
</div>
<div class="normal">

     <p><a href="#" class="opn">Click here</a></p>

  </div>

  <div class="blockbkg" id="bkg" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="cont" id="dlg" style="visibility: hidden;">
      <div class="closebtn" title="Close" id="closebtn"></div>
      <?php echo $data->title; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Anesh: you made 21 questions and never marked one of the answers as answered

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is that your _view.php, that you use to build each element of the list, puts many elements inside the page with the same id [for example `bkg` and `dlg`]. The javascript you are using will then fail to work properly. The id attribute should be unique in the page. Use the class attribute and adjust your javascript accordingly.